# Install compiled linux program on multiple computers

Tags: deployment, make, configuration

I'm sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but when I compile something on linux using the usual "./configure, make, make install" steps, how can I install the programs on other servers without having to recompile?

I am trying to avoid having to install the build tools on production servers, however I need the latest version of a particular piece of software, so using RPMs isn't an option in this case.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So.. would you be ok with making your own RPMs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to have mass deployment of particular software source.

There are several solutions to this,

1. Make script that will automate "./configure, make, make install" which will accompany with source tar or `wget` source from url and compiles it.
2. Other solution can be make rpm or deb package (or specific to your distro) from latest build

   - [Making binary package from source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/)
   - [Creating rpm from source](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package)

Hope this will solve your problem.